# Google map direcion api convert hours to mins

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two textbox in my web page. In textbox1 location A gets filled & in textbox2 location B gets filled. My problem is in log distance it shows 
e.g. 3 hours 15 mins but to do some calculation I don't want this format to come I want it like this it should show 195 mins & so on. Below is my script which I used since I am beginner in js I don't have any idea to get it into mins format. Please help me.

```
<input name="txtSource" type="text" id="txtSource" class="inners" placeholder="From Area" />

<input name="txtDestination" type="text" id="txtDestination" class="inners"  placeholder="To Area" />
```

JS

```
var source, destination;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            debugger;
            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: mumbai
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

            //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
                    var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
                    var dvDurationC = document.getElementById("dvDurationC")
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.value = parseFloat(distance);
                    dvDuration.innerHTML = duration;
                    dvDuration.value = (duration);
                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Instead of using the text attribute i would use the duration.value. There you have the seconds and then you can easily calculate the minutes, hours and whatever time format you wanna have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the numeric value returned by the directions matrix for the [Duration](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Duration), it is always in seconds, to convert that to minutes, divide by 60.

```
var duration = (response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value/60).toFixed(0);
var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
dvDuration.innerHTML = duration + " minutes";
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfy6k1r6/)